# I can't insert a row into table with auto_increment column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble on inserting a query into a table with auto increment column.

I have searched a lot of pages but did not get any solution from there yet.

Below is my inserting query.

```
Insert into Person ( FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Telephone, Email) 
    values (  "john","done","seoul","seoul","seoul","11776","1234","hello@world.com");
```

My table consists of ID, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, state, zipcode, telephone, email.

I have also tried to insert the query with id column and NULL value, but it didn't work also.

If I execute above query, I always get the error message,

**Error Code: 1644. An Id below or equal to 0**

And this is my workbench snapshot of my table.
[image]

I have set the auto increment as 1 and truncated table also, but.. it still doesn't work..

I have no idea how to solve this error.

Comment: Probably not related to your question, but, use single quotes instead of double quotes around text.

Comment: `show create table Person`

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at http://sqlfiddle.com/?
If not, you may just want to create a clean, new table (`person2`), populate that with any data still in `person` that you need, then change the table names.

Comment: Error code 1644 suggests that you have a trigger on this table that checks the values and raises this error (1644 is a user defined error). Pls check if you have a before or after insert trigger and if yes, then show us its code.

Comment: @Shadow I will check it!

Comment: @Shadow Thank you! You are right!! After I dropped one of triggers it works. I appreciate

Answer (score 2):

[Error code 1644](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html) is a user defined error:

> Error: 1644 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION)
>
> Message: Unhandled user-defined exception condition

This, along with the very specific error message, suggests that you have a before or after insert trigger on this table that checks the value of the `id` field and raises this error.

You need to check this trigger and either correct it or you need to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
Insert into Person (id, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, ZipCode, Telephone, Email) 
values (default,  "john","done","seoul","seoul","seoul","11776","1234","hello@world.com");
```

Comment: using DEFAULT as the value of AUTO_INCREMENT field worked for me.